# finding the number of seconds since it last struck 12 when user inputs an hour, minute, and seconds (c++)

Tags: c++, int

I'm trying to write a function that takes the time as three integer arguments (hours, minutes and seconds) and returns the number of seconds since the last time the clock “struck 12.” Use this function to calculate the amount of time in seconds between two times, both of which are within one 12-hour cycle of the clock.

This is the code I have and every time I compile it, it won't stop running.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int passedSeconds(int, int, int);
int difference(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int hour1, minute1, second1;
    int hour2, minute2, second2;

    cout << "1. Enter hours, minutes and seconds (range 00:00:00 - 23:59:59): ";
    cin >> hour1 >> minute1 >> second1;

    while(hour1 > 23 || minute1 > 59 || second1 > 59)
    {
        if(hour1 < 23)
            cout << "\nEnter correct hours value!";
        if(minute1 < 59)
             cout << "\nEnter correct minutes value!";
        if(second1 < 59)
             cout << "\nEnter correct seconds value!";

        cout << "\n1. Enter hours, minutes and seconds: ";
        cin >> hour1 >> minute1 >> second1;
    }
    cout << "Passed seconds from last 12 (am or pm): " << passedSeconds(hour1, minute1,second1);

    cout << "\n2. Enter hours, minutes and seconds (range 00:00:00 - 23:59:59): ";
    cin >> hour2 >> minute2 >> second2;

    while(hour2 > 23 || minute2 > 59 || second2 > 59)
    {
        if(hour2 < 23)
            cout << "\nEnter correct hours value!";
        if(minute2 < 59)
            cout << "\nEnter correct minutes value!";
        if(second2 < 59)
            cout << "\nEnter correct seconds value!";

        cout << "\n2. Enter hours, minutes and seconds: ";
        cin >> hour2 >> minute2 >> second2;
    }
    cout << "\nDifference between two times is "
         << difference(hour2, minute2, second2) - difference(hour1, minute1, second1) 
         << " seconds.";

    return 0;
}

int passedSeconds(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    if(hour >= 12)
        hour -= 12;

    return hour * 60 * 60 + minute * 60 + second;
}

int difference(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    return hour * 60 * 60 + minute * 60 + second;
}
```

Comment: The first thing I noticed, if you have nested if statements, you need to use { } to surround the rest of the following code block.

Comment: _'it won't stop running'_ I'd suspect this happens because either `(hour1 > 23 || minute1 > 59 || second1 > 59)` or `(hour2 > 23 || minute2 > 59 || second2 > 59)` always evaluate to true. Did you check these values with a debugger?

Comment: @Cyber Yeees! There's currently that hyped Apple bug, demonstrating clearly **how bad** this can be :D ...

Comment: When I am entering valid values of hr,min and sec, the code is running perfectly. What is the problem?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar thats what i was wondering. i am running the code on mac os x mavericks and using the program coderunner. for some reason whenever i compile it works, but it actually runs it will just run infinitely.

Comment: It is not running infinitely in my Ubuntu OS. Giving proper resutls.

Comment: @cvilex _'it will just run infinitely.'_ I'm afraid you have to elaborate more about the exact behavior. The while loops are designed to run infinite when invalid input was given?!?

Comment: Cosmetic: The tests that are supposed to warn for erroneous input are the wrong way around.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it will take in the first hour, minute, and second input and even when its in correct format it will repeat the phrase "input correct value for hour, minute, second" phrases.

Comment: @cvilex What would you consider to be _'correct format'_? Can you edit your question please, to show what you're actually entering from the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling your code with the Visual studio compiler and with a GCC Compiler, and everything works fine here.
One obvious bug in your code:

```
if(hour1 < 23)
    cout << "\nEnter correct hours value!";
if(minute1 < 59)
    cout << "\nEnter correct minutes value!";
if(second1 < 59)
    cout << "\nEnter correct seconds value!";
```

in the first and second while loop, you want to ouput an error message if your hours are INvalid. Now you display them if they are valid, so change your `<` to `>` .

Like I said, The program worked correctly, if I run it in a console, waiting for my input. 
However, if I ran it some online compilers, I noticed what you said. This was because I could not use the program as a console. Try giving in all data that you read in at the same time...

I went to CodeRunner's website and saw this screenshot:
[image: Program input]

I don't know if you tried it, but try giving in the whole program input, before starting.. So something like this:

```
23 25 14
14 15 49
```

(note that this leaves no room for error checking and asking for new input. You will have to handle that in a different way...)

Sadly I could not test this in CodeRunner, since I don't own any OSX devices.

(I also could not respond as a comment, because I don't have enough points yet)

I hope it helped you!